# VSTS - How work with change-set comments?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops, tfs-code-review

We are using the visualstudio.com as our Project Manager provider. We've just  starting using comments on the changeset to do Code-Reviews after commits.

Like this:

[image: VSTS changelog comments]

I have some doubts about using it:

- Is this way of use changeset comments like Code-Review is the right way? If not, why this even exists on the VSTS?
- As I see, the only way I get notifications about those comments is when I mark someone on the comment using "@". There is any other way to get notifications about these comments like any Visual Studio Extensions?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether use changeset for code review, it’s depend on your work around (code view before check in or after check in).

**If the changes are always approved to check in VSTS and you just want to discuss for code review**, of cause you can use changeset to meet your requirement. And the functions of changeset as (you can find in [changesets](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/find-view-changesets)):

> You can view a changeset to see what the exact file changes were,
>   discover the owner's comments, find linked work items, and see if any
>   policy warnings were triggered

**If changes need to be approved by code reviewers before check in VSTS**, you should not use changeset, you need to use [code review](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/get-code-reviewed-vs#request-a-code-review) instead.

For notifications, you can set in notification settings (https://account.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_notifications) as you want, such as you can set to notice when code is checked in or code review changes etc.

[image]

Comment: Can you have any documentation about creating / configuring commits policies? I will explorer all possibilities to find one who improve our productivity! Thanks for the help,

Comment: What do you mean commits polices? There has check-in polices you can refer https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/add-check-policies.